# Cannot add repository account in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I don't know why I cannot add a repository account in Xcode.

Product -- Version
Xcode -- 7.3.1
git -- 2.8.1
OSX -- 10.11.5

[screenshot from xcode/preferences/accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K3qM.png)

Comment: Did you enter your apple id first?

Comment: Yes, my Apple ID is already listed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Under preverences / source control, "enable source control" was not checked. Once checked, I was able to add my GitHub remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your project to your repository with git bash like this:

```
$ cd /your/project/path/
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:ali/first_app.git # Or other repo URLs
$ git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and it's refs for the first time
$ git push origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

Hope be useful.

Comment: My apps directory is on my remote repository and can use GitHub Desktop to commit and sync w/o issue. What I cannot do is enable source control in Xcode.